# Как сделать имитацию клика по ссылке с помощью js

Tags: javascript

Мне нужно сделать клик по ссылке(кнопка для добавления товара) на js. Можно ли сделать клик когда страница загрузится?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вот так:

```js
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function(){///// событие выполняется после загрузки страницы
    const link = document.getElementById('test');////берём ссылку
    link.click()/////кликаем по ней
})
```

```html
<a href="https://google.com" id="test">Ссылка</a>
```

Comment: ?checkout:1198 Uncaught TypeError: link.click is not a function
    at HTMLDocument.<anonymous> у меня выходит такая ошибка

Comment: какой у вас html?